# Is there a way to write a custom BCE loss in pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

I am writing a custom BCE in pytorch but in some cases it returns -inf and nan most cases. Which is due to the log function.

```
bce_loss=y_true*torch.log2(y_pred) +(one_torch-y_true)*torch.log2(one_torch-y_pred)
```

Is there a way to rewrite this? Note y_pred is a sigmoid output which is between 0 and 1.

Comment: The second term should be `... +(one_torch-y_true)*torch.log2(one_torch-y_pred) `

Comment: This would not resolve the issue. The problem here is that log 0 is -inf, so in cases whereby y_pred = 0 or y_pred = 1, there would be -inf generated which inturn gives the final answer to be -inf or nan.

Comment: I don't know how your calculating y_pred but in most algorithms it won't be exactly 1 or 0 but a number that's very close to and in that case you won't get nan out. How are you getting y_pred?

Comment: Yea, the same thing I thought I would only get values very close to 0 and 1. But, i got cases where it was exactly 1  and 0 as well.

Comment: You could add a very small amount to the 0 values and take a way a small amount from the 1 values. Or you could skip over those values all together. Can't help anymore without knowing what model your using.

Answer (score 1):

You can clamp the preds to stop from log error.

`y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)`